# Jenkins Pipeline pulls entire source code for jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I was playing Jenkins 2.0 with multibranch pipeline with one master server plus a couple of slave nodes.

The *Jenkinsfile* looks like:

```
node('slave') {
    stage 'Checkout'
    checkout scm
    stage 'Build'
    ...
}
```

We see that the plugin pulls the entire source code on the master node in order to get *Jenkinsfile* and then pull the entire source tree again on the slave nodes.  Is there a way to have the master only pull *Jenkinsfile*?

Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion it isn't possible because you can split Jenkins file into smaller and load this using load method. Checkout one file from repository could cause a problems and probably this is reason why entrie source code on master node.

Comment: It would be nice if in the job configuration, with option to configure to pull only some files/folders.

Answer (score 1):

See [JENKINS-33273](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33273). The current SCM plugins do not offer a way of retrieving a single file without doing a complete checkout.